# Why does foldr use a helper function?

Tags: haskell, fold

In explaining `foldr` to Haskell newbies, the canonical definition is

```
foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr _ z []     =  z
foldr f z (x:xs) =  f x (foldr f z xs)
```

But in GHC.Base, `foldr` is defined as

```
foldr k z = go
          where
            go []     = z
            go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

It seems this definition is an optimization for speed, but I don't see why using the helper function `go` would make it faster. The source comments ([see here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#foldr)) mention inlining, but I also don't see how this definition would improve inlining.

Comment: One detail not mentioned yet: ghc only inlines a function when it is fully-applied, *syntactically*, in its left-hand side. This is pretty weird and ugly if you're used to thinking about currying and creating nice point-free-style code. That's why you sometimes see silly lambdas to the right of the `=` in optimized code.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I can add some important details about GHC's optimization system.

The naive definition of `foldr` passes around a function. There's an inherent overhead in calling a function - especially when the function isn't known at compile time. It'd be really nice to able to inline the definition of the function if it's known at compile time.

There are tricks available to perform that inlining in GHC - and this is an example of them.  First, `foldr` needs to be inlined (I'll get to why later). `foldr`'s naive implementation is recursive, so cannot be inlined. So a worker/wrapper transformation is applied to the definition. The worker is recursive, but the wrapper is not. This allows `foldr` to be inlined, despite the recursion over the structure of the list.

When `foldr` is inlined, it creates a copy of all of its local bindings, too. It's more or less a direct textual inlining (modulo some renaming, and happening after the desugaring pass). This is where things get interesting. `go` is a local binding, and the optimizer gets to look inside it. It notices that it calls a function in the local scope, which it names `k`. GHC will often remove the `k` variable entirely, and will just replace it with the expression `k` reduces to. And then afterwards, if the function application is amenable to inlining, it can be inlined at this time - removing the overhead of calling a first-class function entirely.

Let's look at a simple, concrete example. This program will echo a line of input with all trailing `'x'` characters removed:

```
dropR :: Char -> String -> String
dropR x r = if x == 'x' && null r then "" else x : r

main :: IO ()
main = do
    s <- getLine
    putStrLn $ foldr dropR "" s
```

First, the optimizer will inline `foldr`'s definition and simplify, resulting in code that looks something like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    s <- getLine
    -- I'm changing the where clause to a let expression for the sake of readability
    putStrLn $ let { go [] = ""; go (x:xs) = dropR x (go xs) } in go s
```

And that's the thing the worker-wrapper transformation allows.. I'm going to skip the remaining steps, but it should be obvious that GHC can now inline the definition of `dropR`, eliminating the function call overhead. This is where the big performance win comes from.

Answer (score 18):

GHC cannot inline recursive functions, so

```
foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr _ z []     =  z
foldr f z (x:xs) =  f x (foldr f z xs)
```

cannot be inlined. But

```
foldr k z = go
      where
        go []     = z
        go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

is not a recursive function. It is a non-recursive function with a local recursive definition!

This means that, as @bheklilr writes, in `map (foldr (+) 0)` the `foldr` can be inlined and hence `f` and `z` replaced by `(+)` and `0` in the new `go`, and great things can happen, such as unboxing of the intermediate value.

Answer (score 14):

As the comments say:

```
-- Inline only in the final stage, after the foldr/cons rule has had a chance
-- Also note that we inline it when it has *two* parameters, which are the
-- ones we are keen about specialising!
```

In particular, note the "we inline it when it has *two* parameters, which are the ones we are keen about specialising!"

What this is saying is that when `foldr` gets inlined, it's getting inlined only for the specific choice of `f` and `z`, not for the choice of the list getting folded.  I'm not expert, but it would seem it would make it possible to inline it in situations like

```
map (foldr (+) 0) some_list
```

so that the inline happens in this line and not after `map` has been applied.  This makes it optimizable in more situations and more easily.  All the helper function does is mask the 3rd argument so `{-# INLINE #-}` can do its thing.

Answer (score 8):

One tiny important detail not mentioned in other answers is that GHC, given a function definition like

```
f x y z w q = ...
```

cannot inline `f` until all of the arguments `x`, `y`, `z`, `w`, and `q` are applied. This means that it's often advantageous to use the worker/wrapper transformation to expose a minimal set of function arguments which must be applied before inlining can occur.