# Why are some Prelude functions defined in terms of a locally defined function?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I was taking a look at some prelude functions to teach a workmate about recursion and I found that some are written in rather a *weird* way. Example:

```
{-# NOINLINE [1] zipWith #-}
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith f = go
  where
    go [] _ = []
    go _ [] = []
    go (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : go xs ys
```

Why is it written as a call to `go` where `go` is defined right afterwards? IMO a more *natural* way to define it is:

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith _ [] _ = []
zipWith _ _ [] = [] 
zipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith f xs ys
```

I guess it is due to some *inline / loop-fusion / lazy / whatever-feature* that allow `GHC` to optimize better, but this is the point in which Haskell becomes quite obscure to me. Can anyone explain (as easier as possible) the reason for such a function definition, if there is any.

### Edits

Many comments, @AndrewRay's answer and in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243014/why-does-foldr-use-a-helper-function), point in the direction of inlining as the reason for such an auxiliar local function. Nevertheless, `zipWith` is marked with the pragma `NOINLINE [1] zipWith`, which, up to [GHC's user guide: 7.13.5.5. Phase control](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#noinline-pragma), means to **not** inline before first phase and maybe inline afterwards (for whatever this means). In the linked question, the PO refers to `foldr` which is implemented using the same trick but without any PRAGMA. I'd argue that the author is avoiding inlining but my knowledge in this is small.

### Edit 2

added link to [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#zipWith) definition of `zipWith`

Comment: To avoid passing the `f` each time.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's a quick answer!. Can you elaborate a little bit more? It doesn't seem obvious since `go` is actually passed, and `go` contains `f` in its definition.... isn't it?

Comment: "More natural" is in the eye of the beholder. To me `go` is very natural. It zips its two list arguments. Zips with what? With something it knows about. That "something" is irrelevant to the rcursive machinery of zipping.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. There is nothing subjective to Occam's razor. `go` is a new entity, and there is no concept underlying it — they did not even come up with a real name. So it is an elaboration, and it is, denotationally, extraneous — _unnatural_.

Comment: You don't even have the most readable version of `go`. Define `go (x:xs) (y:ys)` first, then the other two base cases reduce to the single case `go _ _ = []`.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov `go` is a closure over `f`; I'd say that's pretty conceptual.

Comment: @chepner Closure is [such a wide term](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33307944) that your sentence substantiates `go` no more than if you said _"`go` is a function"_. Besides, _"closure"_ is quite an extraneous concept itself — an implementation detail! Then again, I do not think people use this concept of closure in the context of Haskell programming so often. So, if `go` is nothing but a closure, it hardly deserves a name, and your argument fortifies mine: the definition without `go` is indeed objectively more natural.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov Fine, pick whatever precisely defined term you want.

Comment: @chepner I did not mean to sound abrasive. My point though is exactly that no precise definition for the role of `go` in `zipWith` has come up so far, and moreover that it is not clear whether it needs to be there at all.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov I always say, be careful with sharp tools, you can cut yourself.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Occam's razor does not cut humans, only ideas.

Comment: A `NOINLINE[1]` pragma doesn't mean "don't inline at all." It means "don't inline until the first optimization round stabilizes." This is important for making sure it has an opportunity to participate in `foldr`/`build` fusion before simple inlining is tried. `foldr` itself not having the inlining delay suggests something about the order in which optimizations are applied, but I'm not totally sure what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Willem Van Onsem mentioned in his comment, this means that `f` doesn't need to be passed in each recursive call.

Your version of the function uses the recursive call `zipWith f xs ys`. Because `f` is an argument of `zipWith`, it has to get passed repeatedly. This means that it isn't obvious from looking at `zipWith` that `f` never changes from one level of recursion to the next.

The `Prelude` version uses the recursive call `go xs ys`, which immediately signals that every recursive call to `go` makes use of the same `f`. Being able to immediately notice invariants like this helps us reason logically about our code.

**EDIT**: I had previously believed that inlining wasn't relevant here, but  Carl and Daniel Wagner both point out that the thunk `f` only needs to be evaluated once and substituted in the definition of `go`, rather than being reevaluated for every recursion as would be the case in your definition of `zipWith`.

You also mention loop-fusion, which is the process of merging adjacent traversal functions into a single traversal. Since this is already a single traversal, that doesn't apply here either.

Comment: Is `zipWith` with `go` self-recursive though?

Comment: It's 100% about performance of compiled code. Making the top-level definition non-recursive allows it to be inlined, which results in `go` being defined someplace where `f` is in scope, which means that if `f` is known it will get inlined into the recursive part. This reduces the use of indirect function calls for potentially significant speedups.

Comment: You say it's not about performance, but it actually is. If you make a closure as in GHC's Prelude, you copy the pointer to `f`'s thunk once, then look it up in the closure once per list element you produce. If you don't, as in the proposed alternative implementation, you copy the pointer to `f`'s thunk once per list element you produce, plus then still have to look it up in the newly created closure. GHC is smart enough to *sometimes* eliminate this latter cost, so these days this technique is only faster when multiple arguments are read-only, but it wasn't always so.

Comment: @Carl, that's a fair point; I didn't consider `zipWith` itself being inlined.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I had thought that that was optimized away in any case, but I'll defer to your expertise on that one.

Comment: Hi @AndrewRay. Thanks for answering, but `zipWith` is marked with `NOINLINE [1] zipWith` pragma, which makes me hesitate about your point. Check for the edit if you will

Comment: @Ismor, that indicates that `zipWith` should not be inlined itself. The point about inlining `f` in the definition of `go` still stands unless I'm misunderstanding the pragma statement.

Comment: @AndrewRay In the question linked in the edit, the accepted answer says that `f` is inlined in the definition of `go` when `foldr` is inlined. I am not trying to argue against you and you're probably right, but this is somehow contradictory information. (@Carl's comment actually is about inlining `zipWith` so `f` can be inlined too)